# Theme is not applied after horizontal scroll

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

In my  mobile application I have theme as: `<div data-role="page" id="myPage" data-theme="b" >`  . I have one table in inner div.
Theme b is applied correctly but if suppose I scroll horizontally then theme is not applicable after scroll. Means theme is applied to only visible screen before scroll and after scroll there is no theme. This issue is only for horizontal scroll, for vertical scroll it works perfectly.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Here is my screen shot !

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: they are lying on same div if not try to add on each div data-theme="b"

Comment: @ArpitSrivastava Thanks for reply, Yes I had added data-theme="b" to all div but still same issue.

Comment: Suppose This is my code [link](http://jsfiddle.net/X8yXe/1/) Actually I had made one hard coded table, In real example it is created at run time according to server response. Here theme is not apply in jsfiddle

Comment: just add class on div id="portfoliowrapper" class="ui-header ui-bar-b" or you want to apply any class just place on div id="portfoliowrapper" the class and you will get desired result...

Comment: No it is not working. Now my output is as image added in my original question.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/X8yXe/4/  Updated your jsbin to include styles. Styles seem fine to me in jsfiddle. Do you mean the blue background doesn't extend outside of the bounds of the page?

Comment: @Jeemusu  it is not scrolling now.

Comment: Are you seriously going to implement horizontal scrollbars into a mobile application?

Comment: @Jeemusu  yes I mean blue background doesn't extend outside of the bounds of the page.

Comment: @PPD As far as I can tell jQuery Mobile does not support, and hopefully will never support the ability to scroll horizontally outside the bounds of a page, it's just not a very mobile friendly way to display information. Ideally you should rework the table to fit within the confides of a mobile devices screen. If you can't do that then you'd be better to embed any content wider than the page within an iframe, or a fixed width container, and allow the user to scroll horizontally within that area only.

Comment: Further to my comment above, this is one way you could do it. It doesn't look pretty, but I will leave that to you. http://jsfiddle.net/X8yXe/15/

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/X8yXe/7/ by adding position:fixed to the header and width 100% you can make it stick. Fixed will float the div so the table will not appear bellow but literally under it. To solve this I added a second height div to push the table down.

position:fixed works on Android and iOS 5, earlier iOS versions does not support position:fixed though.

Comment: I also added style="overflow:auto" to the page div to get the scroll bar back.

Comment: Seeing as your using jQuery Mobile, you could of just used `data-position="fixed" ` on the header instead of the css.

Comment: @Jeemusu thanks for reply but after using data-position="fixed"  also does not solve issue.

Comment: @Ekim after adding style="overflow:auto"  scrollbar is visible only in jsfiddle but not on mobile simulator.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way you could get around your problem, also addressed some other areas of your code.

Here is the result of the below changes -> http://jsfiddle.net/X8yXe/17/ .

Firstly, I would wrap your content with the `data-role="content"` paramater just to keep this semantic with [the way things are done](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/pages/page-anatomy.html) in jQuery Mobile.

```
<div data-role="page" id="orderbookpage" data-theme="b" >
    <div data-role="header" align="center" data-theme="b">
        <a href="#" data-rel="back" data-icon="arrow-l">Back</a>
        <h1>MyPage </h1>
        <a href="MainMenu.html"  data-icon="grid">Menu</a>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content" data-theme="b">
        <div id="portfoliowrapper" align="center"  data-theme="b"></div>
        <p>Some random content, so we can see the scroll in relation to other content. </p>
    </div>       
</div>
```

Secondly you can apply the following CSS to the #protfoliowrapper to achieve a contained horizontal scrolling div.

```
#portfoliowrapper {
    width:93%;  
    white-space: nowrap;
    height:40px;
    padding: 20px;
    overflow: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden; /* hide scrollbar */

    /* make it stand out */
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin: 0px auto;
    background-color: #eef1f1;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,0 0, 0 100%, from(#f3f3f3), to(#e2e2e2));
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 0 0 #fff inset, 0 1px 0 #fff inset;
}
```

​Thirdly and finally, a tip. Your using jQuery Mobile, so why not use it? Why use standard javaScript when your loading jQuery?

Instead of doing:

```
document.getElementById('portfoliowrapper').innerHTML = theader + tbody + tfooter;
```

You can do this:

```
$('#portfoliowrapper').append(theader + tbody + tfooter);​
```